# gedit snippets are not activated?

Tags: ubuntu, text-editors, gedit, snippets

I want to use facility of gedit to insert snippets.

The documentation suggests ([doc](http://live.gnome.org/Gedit/Plugins/Snippets)):

**Using snippets**

*Install the plugin. Menu: Tools -> Manage Snippets. A dialog will appear and you can start add snippets. Select a 'Language' (or Global for global snippets). Start adding snippets.*

I found the folder */usr/share/gedit-2/plugins/snippets* where all snippet xmls are located, but unfortunately was not able neither use snippets nor edit them.

How is it possible to use snippets in gedit? I am using the version 2.30.3.

Comment: I have found an answer! Edit->Preferences->Plugins->Snippets! BTW, where is the possibility to answer own questions!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit->Preferences->Plugins->Snippets!